# 6 table join SQL query difficulty

Tags: mysql

I have the following 6 tables(simplified for posting):

Orders:

```
    +----------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+
    | Order_ID | Sales_Area_ID| Project_Status_ID | Active       | 
    +----------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+
    |  1       | 3            | 2                 | 1            |
    |  2       | 2            | 2                 | 1            |
    |  3       | 3            | 3                 | 1            |
    |  4       | 2            | 1                 | 1            |
    +----------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+
```

Order_Release:

```
    +------------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
    | Order_Release_ID | Order_ID| Sales_Release_Date | Currency_Rate      |  
    +------------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
    |  1               | 1       | 2016/06/25         | 1                  |
    |  2               | 2       | 2016/02/19         | 1                  |
    |  3               | 1       | 2016/06/23         | 1.2                |
    |  4               | 2       | 2016/06/22         | 1                  |
    +------------------+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Rooflight_Request (product type A):

```
    +----------------------+---------+--------+---------+--------+----------------+
    | Rooflight_Request_ID | Order_ID| Price  | Discount| Qty    | Record_Active  |  
    +----------------------+---------+--------+---------+--------+----------------+
    |  1                   | 1       | 1200   | 50      | 2      | 1              |
    |  2                   | 2       | 1178   | 0       | 1      | 1              |
    |  3                   | 1       | 500    | 20      | 12     | 1              |
    |  4                   | 2       | 3521   | 0       | 1      | 0              |
    +----------------------+---------+--------+---------+--------+----------------+
```

Rooflight_Request (product type B):

```
    +----------------------------+---------+--------+---------+--------+----------------+
    | Rooflight_Extra_Request_ID | Order_ID| Price  | Discount| Qty    | Record_Active  |  
    +----------------------------+---------+--------+---------+--------+----------------+
    |  1                         | 1       | 200    | 50      | 1      | 0              |
    |  2                         | 2       | 178    | 0       | 3      | 1              |
    |  3                         | 1       | 50     | 20      | 5      | 1              |
    |  4                         | 3       | 121    | 0       | 10     | 1              |
    +----------------------------+---------+--------+---------+--------+----------------+
```

Sales_Area:

```
    +---------------+----------------+--------------+
    | Sales_Area_ID | Sales_Area_Name| Active       | 
    +---------------+----------------+--------------+
    |  1            | East           | 0            |
    |  2            | Lon 1          | 1            |
    |  3            | Lon 2          | 1            |
    |  4            | USA            | 1            |
    +---------------+----------------+--------------+
```

Project_Status:

```
    +-------------------+----------------+
    | Project_Status_ID | Project_Status |
    +-------------------+----------------+
    |  1                | Quote          |
    |  2                | Released       |
    |  3                | Invoiced       |
    |  4                | Released_PM    |
    |  5                | Credit_Note    |
    +-------------------+----------------+
```

I am trying to write a query that returns the total value of order items in columns grouped by sales area rows.  So I would like all the sales areas returned even if the item totals are zero.
I am trying to work with the following rules: within an order release date window, only adding active items to totals.  So far I have this query:

```
    SELECT salesArea.Area_Name,

            (SELECT SUM(((rr.Price - (rr.Price * (rr.Discount /100))) / orders.Currency_Rate) * rr.Quantity) 
                FROM Rooflight_Request AS rr
                WHERE rr.Order_ID = orders.Order_ID
                AND rr.Record_Active = 1 
                AND rr.Alternative_Option <> 1
            ) AS Rooflights_Total,

            (SELECT SUM(((rx.Price - (rx.Price * (rx.Discount /100))) / orders.Currency_Rate) * rx.Quantity)
                FROM Rooflight_Extra_Request AS rx
                WHERE rx.Order_ID = orders.Order_ID
                AND rx.Record_Active = 1
                AND rx.Alternative_Option <> 1
            ) AS Extras_Total

            FROM Orders AS orders
                LEFT JOIN Order_Release AS orderRelease ON
                    orders.Order_ID = orderRelease.Order_ID
                LEFT JOIN Project_Status AS projectStatus ON 
                    orders.Project_Status_ID = projectStatus.Project_Status_ID 
                    AND projectStatus.Record_Active = 1 
                LEFT JOIN Sales_Area AS salesArea ON 
                    orders.Sales_Area_ID = salesArea.Sales_Area_ID 
                    AND salesArea.Record_Active = 1

            WHERE orderRelease.Sales_Release_Date >= 2016/06/22
            AND orderRelease.Sales_Release_Date <= 2016/06/29
            AND (projectStatus.Project_Status = 'Invoiced' 
                OR projectStatus.Project_Status = 'Released' 
                OR projectStatus.Project_Status = 'Released PM')
            GROUP BY orders.Order_ID
```

The query returns zero results.  If I remove the sales_Release_Date where clauses I got lots of results but it is not totally the order items for each only taking the first result set from each.
I have tried lots of different arrangements but cannot seem to crack this one.  Cany anybody help?  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If sales_Release_Date is a string include the condition in quotes..

```
orderRelease.Sales_Release_Date >= '2016/06/22'
```

If it of type date, you need to include date functions.. `str_to_date`

Comment: Hi Harika, my apologies it is a string and the query with ticks round it does run but it does not total all the order items, I only get one orders worth of items per sales area.  So if I allow a 6 month date window I am expecting to see hundreds of thousands of value in the results but I am only getting a few....  Really struggling with this one

Comment: As the query should return results within a date range, it is better to have this fields as a date field rather than a string field..is it possible to convert to datetime? then you could do something like this..`WHERE orderRelease.Sales_Release_Date between str_to_date('06/22/2016 00:00:00','%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s') and str_to_date('06/29/2016 23:59:59','%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s')`

Comment: If conversion to date datatype is an an issue, try this .. `WHERE str_to_date(orderRelease.Sales_Release_Date, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s')  between str_to_date('06/22/2016 00:00:00','%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s') and str_to_date('06/29/2016 23:59:59','%m/%d/%Y %H:%i:%s')`

Comment: Thank you, as stated at the start I have simplified the question to try and make it reasonable for me to try and ask.  The fields are dateTime and it is dateTime objects I am using in the application, the problem is not there it is in the arrangement of the query I believe.  So if I remove the dateTime condition all together and run the query without that part I would expect totals for each area irrelevant of the date but I am only getting one orders worth of items, it is not totally up every orders items for each area?